# Matlab Accessing Elements in Symbolic Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
syms x1 x2 

f1(x1,x2)=x1^2-3*x2+5;
f2(x1,x2)=-2*sin(x1)+5*x2*x1;

M = [f1 ; f2];
disp(M(1));
```

I'm try to create a matrix of symbolic expressions f1 and f2. However, I'm having trouble accessing a particular element within the matrix.This gives me an error because it thinks I want to evaluate the matrix when I just want a particular index. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want symbolic expressions and not functions, you don't need arguments in parentheses:

```
syms x1 x2 

f1 = x1^2-3*x2+5;
f2 = -2*sin(x1)+5*x2*x1;

M = [f1 ; f2];
disp(M(1));
```

---

If you want to put *function handles* into a matrix, Matlab will tell you this is not allowed, and suggest using a cell array instead. Like this:

```
f1 = @(x1,x2) x1^2-3*x2+5;
f2 = @(x1,x2) -2*sin(x1)+5*x2*x1;

M = {f1 , f2};
disp(M{1});
```

Then you can invoke the functions: `M{1}(5,3)` returns 21, `M{2}(5,3)` returns 76.9

Comment: You have a good point. But if I also wanted to maintain the functionality of a function, how I do that?

Comment: Added a function version, with cell array.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
syms x1 x2 

f1 = x1^2-3*x2+5;
f2 = -2*sin(x1)+5*x2*x1;

M = [f1 ; f2];

disp([1 0]*M); % accessing the element 1 by scalar product.
```

This way you can access an element of a vector of functions.